# How correctly deploy a Laravel application from my local environment to my remote server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am pretty new in **Laravel** and I have the following doubt.

I have to migrate a Laravel 5.4 application that I have developed from my local environment to my remote server.

Can I do it in the following way?

1. Take the entire directory containing my local application and upload it into the **/var/www/html** directory of my remote server.
2. Export my local database and import on my remote database.
3. Change the content of the **.env** file.

Now the application should work on my remote server. Is it correct or am I missing something and I have to do something else?

Comment: Give it a try, and you'l find out :)

Comment: It should work,are you getting any error ?

Comment: If you're missing anything it's configuring a webserver like e.g. apache

Comment: your server ..?  window or linux .?

Answer (score 3):

here is the steps

**Installation On Shared Hostings**

- Unzip the main zip file and upload your public_html folder ( upload vendor folder as well)
- Give 777 recursive permission to storage/ and bootstrap/ folder
- Create database in phpmyadmin and import .sql file
- Set Database in .env file
- Move all **public folder** files to root folder in(public_html or your website folder)
- open `index.php`

Replace these lines with

```
 require __DIR__."/../bootstrap/autoload.php";
 $app = require_once __DIR__."/../bootstrap/app.php";
```

To

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Add these line for setting public path

`$app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });` 
(Add this index.php)

Site is ready

**Installation On Linux**

- Unzip the main zip file and upload your html folder (without vendor folder)
- Give 777 permission to storage/ and bootstrap folder
- i.e (Linux: `chmod -R 777 foldername`)
- Run Linux command (composer install or composer update)
- Create database in phpmyadmin and import .sql file from DB folder
- Set Database in .env file
- create vertual host for removing public folder from url

Done

Comment: Only a doubt...I have to upload it on a VPS. Have I to create a virtual host on my remote server? I am accesing using the IP of my VPS server...so...I think that this vistual host will be inaccessible from the outside. So I can declare a virtual host like (myvirtualhost.dev) on my remote server but then how can I reach this virtual host? From outside I  can't contact the inner "myvirtualhost.dev". What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

you'll maybe have to update some packages on your remote server so Laravel can work properly.
More details here : https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting/blob/master/README.md