# How can I upload my local Laravel web project to server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, web-hosting

I work on a website which i made from Laravel and now i need to push it to the server and go live. I'm new to Laravel hosting. Earlier I did coding by pure php and those days i just push the project to server and it works. My server is one.com and this is what i get when i copy my content and try to access the page.

[image]

please help me on this manner! thank you

Comment: You have to point the website to the `/public` folder of your project. I have no idea how to do that at one.com.

Comment: See [How correctly deploy a Laravel application from my local environment to my remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388814/how-correctly-deploy-a-laravel-application-from-my-local-environment-to-my-remot#43393799)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Use .htaccess**

if it isn't already there, create an .htaccess file in the Laravel root directory. Create a .htaccess file your Laravel root directory if it does not exists already. (Normally it is under your public_html folder)
Edit the .htaccess file so that it contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has an Entry Point (which is the `index.php` File). This File lives inside the `public` folder. To go **L-I-V-E** with a Laravel Project, you have to set your Document Root to point to the `public` Directory.

Right now, you can only access your Site by navigating to: http://van.lesthi.com/public/

At the moment of this writing; accessing the URL above throws somewhat of an SQL Error, which you may want to fix first....